# Duistermaat and Kolk: definition of separating family of seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I am reading the book "Distributions: Theory and Applications" by Duistermaat and Kolk. In chapter 8, Definition 8.5., they say that a family of semi-norms $\mathcal{N}$ is separating if

1. For every $x\neq 0$, there exists an $n\in \mathcal{N}$ such that $n(x)\neq 0$.
2. For every $n,m \in \mathcal{N}$, there exists a $p\in \mathcal{N}$, such that $n(x),m(x)\le p(x)$, for all $x$.

However, in every other source I looked at, only the first requirement was stated. Do the authors include the second requirement because given a family of semi-norms that satisfies only the first, we can always extend it to one that also satisfies the second, by say including all finite sums?

Comment: Probably, finite sums of a family of semi-norms should generate the same topology as the original family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you've got it, exactly. Probably for some technical reason they want to have the collection of seminorms be closed under positive-real linear combinations, etc.

Comment: The *directedness* of the family of seminorms yields that the families of balls $\{B_n(x,r): n\in \mathcal N, r>0\}$ are bases of the neighbourhood filters of $x$ and not only subbases.